# Using Pandas to Write to a File within a Samba Share

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-platform, export, samba

I am using a GCP Cloud Function to read from a BigQuery Table and output the results to a CSV file located on a network drive (all the infrastructure parts necessary to communicate with on-prem are in place).  I was wondering whether there is a way to write data out to this location using Pandas and PYSMB?

I have done a fair bit of reading on the topic and couldn't find a way, but thought someone with more experience may have an idea.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,
Scott

Comment: I would recommend checking the [Bigquery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas#download_table_data_using_the_client_library) client libraries by using that you can directly run from local, manipulate using pandas and write the results to local.
 
Also, Could you give a brief about the use case of using Cloud Function in your requirement?